# React, Material UI, how disable button depending on the state 2 switch button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Task: by default, the button is off, how to make it turn on only when switch btn has changed its state, which comes in props, or rather the correct check for it.
I think that validation should take place in handleChangeState.

```
const CustomSwitch = ({name, checked, handleChange}) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(checked);

    const handleChangeState = (event) => {
        setState(!state)
        handleChange(event)
    }

    return (
        <Switch
        required
        checked={state}
        onChange={handleChangeState}
        name={name}
        color="primary"
    />
    )
}

const CustomSaveButton = ({ notifyByEmail,  notifyBySite, notificationType}) => {
    const [isButtonSend, setIsButtonSend] = useState(true);

    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        email: notifyByEmail,
        site: notifyBySite,
    });

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
        //validate here
    }

    return (
        <>
            <TableCell  align="center">
                <CustomSwitch name="site" handleChange={handleChange} checked={notifyBySite} setIsButtonSend={setIsButtonSend}/>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell  align="center">
                <CustomSwitch name="email" handleChange={handleChange} checked={notifyByEmail} setIsButtonSend={setIsButtonSend}/>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">
                <SaveButton
                    variant="text"
                    disabled={isButtonSend}
                    onClick={save}
   
                />
            </TableCell>

        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage `useEffect` with `state` as dependency

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
  email: notifyByEmail,
  site: notifyBySite
});

React.useEffect(() => {
  setIsButtonSend(!(state.email && state.site));
}, [state]);
```

Comment: Maybe I misspelled it, I only need to turn on the button when the position of the switch button has changed and it does not equal the state sent to the props for e-mail and site fields.

Comment: same concept; different logic `setIsButtonSend(!(state.email !== notifyByEmail || state.site !== notifyBySite));`. add dependency for props on useEffect

Comment: Oh thank you very much, my mistake was that I did such checks not in useEffect.